# How do I access other values from within an each

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to figure out how to access values from within an each statement.

My template is returning 2 attributes:

```
Template.home.submissions = function() {
  return( { submissions: Submissions.find(), data: "yes"})
}
```

my template looks like this (using Jade):

```
template(name="mine")
  each submissions
    span= submissions.name
```

This works just fine.
I'd like to access the data value from within the each.  Something like this:

```
template(name="mine")
  each submissions
    span= submissions.name
    span= data
```

But this doesn't work.  How do I access the data value from within the each?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an array or a cursor from your helper in order for `each` to work properly.

It should work with this:

```js
Template.mine.submissions = function() {
  return [{ submissions: Submissions.find(), data: "yes"}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to write the name of the submission and `yes` in each step of the loop.

You could achieve that with the following code:

```
Template.home.submissions = function() {
   var submissions = [];
   _(Submissions.find().fetch(), function(sub){
      sub.data = "yes";
      submissions.push(sub);
   })
   return submissions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to iterate over the `Submissions` collection, using the same `data` value across each element.

You can use the `../` syntax to access the parent data context. Here's how you'd do it with Spacebars (I'm not familiar with Jade):

```
<template name="mine">
  {{#with submissions}}
    {{! data context is now {submissions: cursor, data: "yes"} }}
    {{#each submissions}} {{! iterate over previously mentioned cursor }}
      {{! data context is now (an element of the Submissions collection) }}
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{../data}}</span> {{! access the data property from the parent data context}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

I'm not sure if the `../` syntax works in Jade, but looking through the mquandalle/meteor-jade code, it looks like they defer to Spacebars when parsing the `#{ }` and `{{ }}` syntax. So while `span= ../data` might not work, `span #{../data}` or `span {{../data}}` should.